# How do I loop through a collection of LINQ to Entities collection?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ to Entities call to fill a collection variable:

```
var insuredFamily = db.Insureds.Where(x => x.ssn.Split('-')[0] == tmp[MemberId])
                      .OrderBy(x => x.fk_relation);
```

How would I go about looping through the items in the collection printing out both the item header and the item value for each row?

I'm new to LINQ to Entities, so all I'm trying to do is loop through a built collection and output the headers and rows to a log file so that I can quickly see what is being returned in the collection without resorting to stepping through each row in the debugger. Is this possible?

If a generic loop is not possible, is it possible to set the data source of a data grid to the collection variable and view the collection in a grid?

Comment: `foreach` loop?

Comment: Yes, but I am not familiar with the syntax for referencing the item header and the item value.
foreach (var familyMember in insuredFamily)
{
    foreach (var item in familyMember)
    {
       header = item.header?
       value = item.value?
    }
}


Is this close?

Comment: `familyMember` is a entity from `Insureds` table. If you want to enumerate some related entities from other table, then inner foreach should look like `foreach(var item in familtyMember.Items)`. You should add definition of `Insured` class. At least show its important properties

Comment: I need something generic enough to work against any table I reference from the database.  foreach (var item in familyMember.Items) gives me a syntax error because .Items is not defined.  What is proper way of looping through all the properties of the Insured class?

Comment: C# is strongly typed, so trying to make a "generic" loop that will work for disparate types is not possible unless you resort to reflection or `dynamic` which are not type-safe and may result in errors at run-time.

Comment: I'm new to LINQ to Entities, so all I'm trying to do is loop through a built collection and output the headers and rows to a log file so that I can quickly see what is being returned in the collection without resorting to stepping through each row in the debugger.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the advice, but it looks like the following two lines of code will do what I need.  I just wanted to visualize the results of my LINQ to SQL queries.

```
var nationalities = db.Nationalities.OrderBy(x => x.pk_Nationality);
dgvResults.DataSource = nationalities;
```

This code will simply put the collection into the data source of my data grid view allowing me to see all the contents.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this can't be a LINQ-to_Entities statement. There's no way to translate `x.ssn.Split('-')[0] == tmp[MemberId]` into SQL. Unless this is EF-Core, that automatically switches to client-side evaluation when the expression contain not-supported part. You're not explicit about that.

Anyway, it's overkill to add logging just to see the content of a collection while debugging. You can use the *immediate window* in Visual Studio to output data when the code stops at a break point.

To make this really helpful, override the `Insured` class's `ToString` method. When I do this with just some `Product` class ...

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}, {1}", this.Name, this.UnitPrice);
}
```

... and break in the debugger right after a line like ...

```
var prod = context.Products;
```

.. then in the immediate window I can type ...

```
?prod.ToList()
```

... which gives me:

```
Count = 6
    [0]: {Nike Air, 150.00}
    [1]: {Web cam, 23.00}
    [2]: {Mouse, 7.00}
    [3]: {Cool pack, 4.50}
    [4]: {Keyboard, 47.30}
    [5]: {Action cam, 73.00}
```

(and some SQL logging)

Note that this is invasive debugging. By calling `ToList`, the query is forced to execute. This *may* change the state in a way that it affects the code's behavior. The same would hold for logging though.